# Pure CSS-Parallax: Inconsistent Scrolling between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, scroll, parallax

I have been playing around with creating a **pure CSS-based parallax scrolling effect** (background scrolls slower than foreground with perspective, transformZ and scale).

I was pretty happy with the result (working in Firefox) until I tested it in Chrome.

In Firefox, I see exactly the desired behavior: The screen shows a background that is bigger than the viewport. Upon scroll, the background moves slowly and a text moves quickly into the view. **The scrolling ends when the bottom of the background layer aligns with the bottom of the viewport. However in Chrome (desktop and mobile), I can scroll a lot further down, misaligning the upper layers and scrolling the background up, revealing a blank white page behind.**

Unfortunately, I do not understand which element is so large that it allows further scrolling. I just want the scrolling to end once the end of the background is reached. It does seem as if no other layer extends further than the background.

I set up a *Minimal Problem Example* on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sgasse/pen/jOOqpEE). It shows the desired (Firefox-like) behavior there, but you might want to look at it by copying the two files and testing in Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Minimal Problem Example</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='parallax.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='parallaxisWrapper'>
            <div class='parallaxisGroup'>
                <div class='layer personalInfo-layer'>
                    This text should scroll up into the viewable area
                </div>

                <div class='layer backimage-layer'>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

```css
/*
   CSS Reset
   http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}



/*
My example starts here
*/

.parallaxisWrapper {
    /* fill screen vertically */
    height: 100vh;
    /* allow only vertical scrolling */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* shift the perspective to allow for parallax scrolling effect
        (perspective - distance) / perspective = scaleFactor
        distance is defined from zero layer, closer objects have to be scaled down and smaller have to be scaled up
    */
    perspective: 4px;
}

.parallaxisGroup {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

[class$='-layer'] {
    /* position all parallax layers absolutely */
    position: absolute;
}


.personalInfo-layer {
    /* keep in the default distance to scroll normally */
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
    width: 80vw;
    height: 55vh;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10vh;
}

.backimage-layer {
    /* transform to the back to scroll slower and adjust scale */
    transform: translateZ(-20px) scale(6);
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/1000) no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    width: 100vw;
    /* adjust background layer width and top anchor to cover the full scrollable background of the upper layers */
    height: 116vh;
}
```

Please do not be confused by the CSS-Reset Code in the beginning. It is just a copied standard. Also, some layers might seem superfluous to you. However this is a *tuned down* version of my actual page.

Any hint on what could cause this behavior or how to make the impression consistent from Firefox to Chrome would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/performant-parallaxing) and as stated in [this Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643213), Chrome (as well as Safari) do not account for the scale when calculating an elements size - hence the unwanted scroll-bar/white space.
Their proposal is to set the perspective origin to the bottom right corner to make elements grow into the 'negative region'.

The following changes are needed to make your example work in Chrome:

- To the `.parallaxisWrapper` class, add `perspective-origin: bottom
  right` (i.e. to the class in which the perspective is set)
- To the `[class$='-layer']` classes, add `transform-origin: bottom right` (i.e. to all classes in which transforms should be executed)

In your example, the backimage-layer is too small compared to the personalInfo-layer, if you change for example the height of the personalInfo-layer from `55vh` to `35vh`, the white space disappears completely.